# Jenkins Git branch variable is not replaced with value correctly

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm currently having troubles with a build on Jenkins, more specifically with the Git plugin in combination with a parameter, but only on a specific job.

I'm having a Jenkins job that builds a release version of our software. The software is inside Git on a branch named 'release/' (for example release/06.03). Because multiple versions are possible I have a properties file where the possible release git branches are defined and I use Extented Choice Parameter to make single select dropdown box

[image]

The user selects one of the release_branch options and enters the patch version number and then the job can be build. This exact same setup works correctly for other release jobs we have where I use the exact same setup and the same properties file. Except for just one job.

The first step in the process (for debugging purposes) is a Windows batch command where I echo the %release_branch% variable.

[image]

Then I checkout the code from Git using the $release_branch variable (I've removed sensitive information from the screenshot below, the correct repository and credentials are filled in)

[image]

After the repository is checked out a groovy script starts where other parameters are determined based on the software that was checked out.

Now when I execute this job and check the loggings some strange stuff is happening (I have again replaced some sensitive information:

- Customer name has been replaced with  <customer >
- The proxy URL has been replaced with  <proxy ip and port >
- The git URL has been replaced with  <git repository url >.git

The sensitive information has been confirmed and definitely works):

---

### **The following Jenkins loggings are from the jobs that goes wrong**

```
Started by user Rick Veenstra
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace D:/Jenkins/builds/git/repositories\<customer>
Running Prebuild steps
[<customer>] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson48240663439325326.bat

D:\Jenkins\builds\git\repositories\<customer>>echo Will checkout from Git using branch: release/06.03 
Will checkout from Git using branch: release/06.03

D:\Jenkins\builds\git\repositories\<customer>>exit 0 
Success build forhudson.tasks.BatchFile@f3d5a79
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository <git repository url>.git
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe init D:\Jenkins\builds\git\repositories\<customer> # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <git repository url>.git
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git1134080240648513421.credentials\" # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: <proxy ip and port>
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress <git repository url>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/refs/heads/release/06.03/*
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.refs/heads/release/06.03.url <git repository url>.git # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.refs/heads/release/06.03.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/refs/heads/release/06.03/* # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.refs/heads/release/06.03.url <git repository url>.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <git repository url>.git
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git993807724023012035.credentials\" # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: <proxy ip and port>
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress <git repository url>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/refs/heads/release/06.03/*
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/refs/heads/$release_branch/release/06.03^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/refs/heads/$release_branch/refs/heads/release/06.03^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 64e002379c30c545cbf05e6c062df2a78990cb1e (refs/remotes/refs/heads/$release_branch/release/06.03)
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 64e002379c30c545cbf05e6c062df2a78990cb1e
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list 64e002379c30c545cbf05e6c062df2a78990cb1e # timeout=10
Notified Stash for commit with id 64e002379c30c545cbf05e6c062df2a78990cb1e
==============================
[-- STARTING GROOVY SCRIPT --]
==============================
Based on the git branch and client the Jenkins parameters will be determined and set.
-- Branch: refs/heads/release/06.03/release/06.03
```

---

As you can see the Windows Batch prints the %release_branch% parameter as "release/06.03" as is correct. But then the parameter is used in the Git plugin and things get messed up. First everything seems fine but then the parameter name $release_branch is printed with right behind it the replaced value.

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/refs/heads/$release_branch/release/06.03^{commit}" #timeout=10
D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/refs/heads/$release_branch/refs/heads/release/06.03^{commit}"
# timeout=10 Checking out Revision 64e002379c30c545cbf05e6c062df2a78990cb1e
(refs/remotes/refs/heads/$release_branch/release/06.03)
```

And then in the groovy script the first $release_branch is replaced with the value again and thus it shows release/06.03 twice

```
-- Branch: refs/heads/release/06.03/release/06.03
```

I'm at a loss as to why the parameter is not replacing properly and why it I don't see the term 'origin' as I see with other loggings, since I only have one remote git server defined I expect something like below

---

### **The following Jenkins loggings are from one of the other jobs that work correctly**

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace D:/Jenkins/builds/git/repositories/<customer 2>
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository <git repository url 2>.git
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe init D:\Jenkins\builds\git\repositories\<customer 2># timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <git repository url 2>.git
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git6918391337668560662.credentials\" # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: 10.30.60.218:8080
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress <git repository url 2>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url <git repository url 2>.git # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url <git repository url 2>.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <git repository url 2>.git
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git6568474183277604659.credentials\" # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: 10.30.60.218:8080
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress <git repository url 2>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/release/06.03^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/refs/heads/release/06.03^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ed0da50edd4e55e8ea1f5fc3c711d191ad217534 (refs/remotes/origin/release/06.03)
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f ed0da50edd4e55e8ea1f5fc3c711d191ad217534
 > D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list 6d3be94009a76663e3efec2daa72dff2754ccab6 # timeout=10
Notified Stash for commit with id ed0da50edd4e55e8ea1f5fc3c711d191ad217534
==============================
[-- STARTING GROOVY SCRIPT --]
==============================
Based on the git branch and client the Jenkins parameters will be determined and set.
-- Branch: origin/release/06.03
```

---

Does anybody know what is going wrong exactly and how to fix the problem?

Kind regards,
Rick

I'm running the following (latest) versions:

- Jenkins: 1.597
- Git plugin: 2.3.4
- Git Parameter plugin: 0.4.0'
- Extended Choice Parameter Plugin: 0.34

Comment: I have a less elaborate setup than OP but I'm on Windows with a build parameter to capture the branch the user wants to build and passing it to "Branches to build". The console output shows the literal value of the environment variable name being passed to git rev-parse instead of the value supplied by the user.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Branches to build" field - enclose the parameter with curly braces so it should look like `refs/heads/${release_branch}. This includes Windows as well.